# Symmetry group and irreducible representation

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, euclidean-geometry, coxeter-groups

Let $S$ be a bounded [*geometric shape*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_shape) in the Euclidean space $E=\mathbb{R^n}$. Assume that the origin of $E$ is a fixed point of every element of the [symmetry group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_group) $G(S)$ of $S$, and assume that $G(S) \le O(n)$.

Let $V:= E \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ be the [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification) of $E$. It is a faithful complex representation of $G(S)$.

**Question**: Under which conditions on $S$, the representation $V$ is irreducible?

*Remark*: Here are two cases where $V$ is not irreducible:

- $G(S) = \{ 1 \}$ and $n>1$,
- the vector space generated by $S$, denoted $ \langle S \rangle$,  is a strict subspace of $E$.

> *For people thinking my question too broad, here are more specific
>   questions.*

Let's assume that $n>1$, $G(S) \neq \{ 1 \}$  and $ \langle S \rangle = E$.

*Question 1*: Is $V$ irreducible if $S$ is a regular polytope?
*Question 2*: If so, can we extend to semiregular polytope?
*Question 3*: If so, what is your better extension?

*Remark*: The symmetry group of any [regular polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polytope) is an irreducible [finite Coxeter group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group#Finite_Coxeter_groups), and every such group is of this form, except those of type $D_n$, $E_6$, $E_7$, and $E_8$ which are symmetry groups of [semiregular polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiregular_polytope).

Comment: What about when $G(S)$ acts transitively on $S$ and $S$ intersects every subspace of $E$ nontrivially?

Comment: Or at least $G$ acts transitively on $S-\{0\}$

Comment: @leibnewtz: Good sufficient condition (assuming the complexification keeps the irreducibility in this case). For example, $O(n)$ acts transitively on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}$ of $E$, and $\mathbb{S}$ intersects every subspace of $E$ nontrivially.    

Now if $G(S)$ is finite whereas $S$ is not, then the action cannot be transitive; this happens for example if $S$ is a regular polytope; now, by definition, it is a polytope whose symmetry group acts transitively on its flags. Is it sufficient to answer Question 1 positively?

Comment: If $G$ is a finite subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ generated by reflections, then  $G$ is a direct product of irreducible such subgroups generated by reflections. Hence if a finite Coxter group $G$ does not have a faithful irreducible complex representation, then $G$ is a direct product of smaller reflection groups.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: so every irreducible finite Coxeter group has a faithful irreducible complex representation?